# Ruby on Rails Gemfile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm new to web developing and doing a self study guide to learn (the odin project). I'm just now getting to the installation of all the different tools I'll need for programming but having an issue. When setting up ruby on rails for Heroku deployment I'm getting a syntax error. I'm following a guide, http://goo.gl/v2LcbU and when I try to do step 7.2 (bundle install --without production) I get a syntax error. I run `ruby -c Gemfile` and the error says `Gemfile:37: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting $end`.

I've tried a few things but I'm confused and not sure what it's trying to say is wrong with line 37. If you look at the guide I linked it had be replace some of the Gemfile and this is what my Gemfile looks like that is causing an error and not allowing me to `bundle install --without production`.

Gemfile
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvVbN.png
I'm linking an image of it because I'm not sure how to link the file correctly yet, sorry.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:       https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group
:doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: If you get answer of your question then you should accept the answer otherwise people still give answer for this question.Please keep that in your mind @user3479630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid:

```
group
:doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

`group` is a method being called, `:doc` is an argument and the `do...end` block is, well, a block. In Ruby, the first method argument needs to immediately follow the method name. Your group should look more like this:

```
group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it was both helpful and informative. I was able to set it up and back to learning!

Comment: Awesome answer @chirs cashwell.

Answer (score 0):

you can see other sample by running rails standard command, like this:

```
rails new apptest
```

it will automatically generate many files, include Gemfile, at bottom of that,  you will see something like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

study from this, add your own gem, enjoy rails:)